# Use <img> tag in Go to display local image

Tags: go, image

How can I use the `<img>` tag to display a local image in Go?

I've tried the following:

```
fmt.Fprintf(w, "</br><img src='" + path.Join(rootdir,  fileName) + "' ></img>")
```

where rootdir = os.Getwd() and fileName is the name of the file.

If I try `http.ServeFile` with the same path then I can download the image, however I would like to embed it in the webpage itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll preface this by saying my Go knowledge is atrocious at best, but the few experiments I've done have involved this a bit, so maybe this will at least point you in the right direction. Basically, the below code uses a Handle for anything under `/images/` that serves files from the `images` folder in your root directory (in my case it was `/home/username/go`). You can then either hardcode `/images/` in your `<img>` tag, or use `path.Join()` as you did before, making `images` the first argument.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net/http"
  "os"
  "path"
)


func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  fileName := "testfile.jpg"
  fmt.Fprintf(w, "<html></br><img src='/images/" + fileName + "' ></html>")
}

func main() {
  rootdir, err := os.Getwd()
  if err != nil {
    rootdir = "No dice"
  }

  // Handler for anything pointing to /images/
  http.Handle("/images/", http.StripPrefix("/images",
        http.FileServer(http.Dir(path.Join(rootdir, "images/")))))
  http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
  http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
package main

import (
   "io"
   "net/http"
   "os"
)

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   f, e := os.Open(r.URL.Path[1:])
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   defer f.Close()
   io.Copy(w, f)
}

func main() {
   http.HandleFunc("/", index)
   new(http.Server).ListenAndServe()
}
```